# Expand $5e^{2x}$ using the power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have scoured the internet for solutions or workthroughs to a similar question to no avail.

I am assuming I need to use either the Taylor or Maclaurin Series but I have no idea where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Well, I suppose you can start from the power series for $e^x$, right? Then replace $x$ by $2x$ ... and finally multiply by 5.

Answer (score 3):

$e^x$ is the function with the "nicest" power series. Most operations on finite polynomials work the same with $e^x$:
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$e^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}$$
$$5e^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{5\cdot2^n}{n!}x^n$$